# how to kill c++ process using c++ and let it do something before hte kill

Tags: c#, c++, process, kill

I am trying to control a process that is written using c++ 
with a windows C# user interface

first I run the process

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

       Process myProcess = new Process();            

       myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "filepath.exe";
       myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
       myProcess.Start();

}
```

This will run the process

Now after I run it for a while I would like to terminate it 
using:

```
process.Kill();
```

However, like the `Ping` command I would like it to generate
some result, write them to a file then kill

So is there a way to find out if another process is trying to kill
this process so I lead it to the write file function

Comment: Set up a signal handler.

Comment: Process.Kill doesn't give any chance to the process to do anything. Use some kind of interprocess communication (simplest one is using names events) and implement this on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

whenever you kill a process you are actually sending it a signal (SIGKILL most likely), so all you need to do is to assign a signal handler for that particular signal, or you can have the same one for several:

```
signal(SIGTERM, &terminateSigHandler);
signal(SIGKILL, &terminateSigHandler);

etc..
```

Comment: It might be out of your knowledge, but does this work for other languages also (namely C++)?

Comment: @cybermonkey I use this all the time to gracefully shot down processes for all sorts of situations.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alex Farber mentioned in his comment, there is no way for `Process.Kill` to execute anything before killing the program.

In this situation I would personally write a function that executes whatever, *then* kills the process.

Example:

```
private void killProcess()
{
    [execute code here prior to killing the process] 

    process.Kill();
}
```